# why size of a struct with only a bit is 4 byte but not 1 byte

Tags: c++, sizeof

I think it should be 1. Because 1 byte is enough to hold this BOOL. And if I comment "BOOL b:1", it becomes a empty struct, and its size is 1 now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum BOOL { FALSE=0, TRUE=1 };
struct A {
  BOOL b:1;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(A)  << std::endl; //output 4.
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: You also shouldn't assume the size of your enum is 1.

Comment: There's a very good chance the enum was 4 bytes long, and the bitfield was also 4 bytes long. For example, I tested it in VS2013 and enum defaults to int, and bitfields reserve the same amount of space as the type specified.

Comment: `unsigned long long ull : 1` is 8 bytes, whereas `char c : 1` is 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

Padding.

If you want the struct to be "packed" (good for memory use,  TERRIBLE for performance), you can ask for that in a compiler-specific nonstandard way.

Comment: I know there is padding. But one byte is enough to do the padding I think. And do you mean that a empty struct will have terrible performance. I don't think so.

Comment: Read up on "access alignment". Most CPUs  cannot access an arbitrary two bytes in a performant fashion.